# Estou fazendo um exercicio HTML CSS - como alinho a esquerda meu texto que está centralizado?

Tags: css, html5

A intenção é o texto ficar alinhado a esquerda ou mesmo justificado  mas não consegui para que ele está apertado e há trechos amontuados um em cima do outro.
E se possível queria um quadrado ao lado do outro, onde estou errando isso ?
Como resolvo isso ?

```css
.titulo-principal { padding-left: 50px; color: lightgray; }

.caixa { position: relative; width: 940px; margin: 0 auto; }

.principal{ background: whitesmoke; border-radius: 10px 20px 30px 20px; width: 350px; margin: 140px; padding:13px 0;

}

.principal li { display: inline-block; width: 350px; padding: 30px 147px; box-sizing: border-box; border: 2px solid lightslategray; border-radius: 10px 20px 30px 10px; font-family: Constantia; line-height: 0.2px; color: dimgray; }

.principal li:hover { border-color: dimgray; }

.principal li:active { border-color: darkgray; }

.principal li:hover h2 { font-size: 34px; } .principal h2{ color: lightslategray; font-family: "Segoe MDL2 Assets"; font-size: xx-large; }

.valor{ color: darkgrey; font-size: xxx-large; }

.simbolos{ font-size: x-large; }

.diamesano{ font-size: x-large; }
```

```html
<main>
    <ul class="principal">
        <li>
            <h2 class="principal-tipoTaxa"> Selic</h2>
            <p class="valor">9,25</p>
            <p class="simbolos"> % ao ano</p>
            <p class="diamesano">Atualizado HOJE</p>
        </li>

        <li>
            <h2 class="principal-tipoTaxa"> Poupança</h2>
            <p class="valor">XX9,25</p>
            <p class="simbolos"> % ao ano</p>
            <p class="diamesano">Atualizado HOJE</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</main>
```

Answer (score -3):

StackOverFlow Help

```
<div class="content">
```

```
    <div class="item first-card">
        <h2 class="principal-tipoTaxa"> Selic</h2>
        <p class="valor">9,25</p>
        <p class="simbolos"> % ao ano</p>
        <p class="diamesano">Atualizado HOJE</p>
    </div>

    <!-- item secund-card elemento filho  -->

    <div class="item secund-card">
        <h2 class="principal-tipoTaxa"> Poupança</h2>
        <p class="valor">XX9,25</p>
        <p class="simbolos"> % ao ano</p>
        <p class="diamesano">Atualizado HOJE</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thiego Sam tudo bem?  Eu aconselharia a usar div neste tipo de situação em que precisamos agrupar elementos dentro de um container.

Answer (score -3):

```
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .content {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-around;
          align-items: center;
        }

        .item {
            background:whitesmoke;
            border-radius: 10px 20px 30px 20px;
            width: 350px; margin: 140px; 
            padding:13px 0;
            text-align: center;
            border: 2px solid lightslategray;
            border-radius: 10px 20px 30px 10px;
        }

        .item:hover {
            border-color: dimgray; 
        }

        .item h2:hover {
            font-size: 34px;
        }

        .first-card .first-card  h2{ 
            color: lightslategray;
            font-family: "Segoe MDL2 Assets"; 
            font-size: xx-large; 
        }

        .valor{
            color: darkgrey;
            font-size: xxx-large;
        }

        .simbolos{ 
            font-size: x-large; 
        }

        .diamesano{
            font-size: x-large;
         }
```